# How to convert hash map keys into list?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hash map and I'm trying to convert the keys to a list. Here's the code:

```
List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();

HashMap<String, ARecord> uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord>();
for(ARecord records:recs){
    if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getId())){
        uniqueRecs.put(records.getId(), records);
    }
}
```

When I try to do

```
List<ARecord> finalRecs = new ArrayList<ARecord>(uniqueRecs.keySet());
```

The error:

> The constructor ArrayList(Set) is undefined".

How can I convert Hashmap keys to `List<ARecord>` finalRecs?

Answer (score 102):

Your `uniqueRecs` has `String` type of the key. You have to do:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(uniqueRecs.keySet());
```

or

```
List<ARecord> values = new ArrayList<>(uniqueRecs.values());
```

Comment: would there be any way to convert List<String> keys into List<ARecord>?

Comment: ARecords in you map are not the keys, they are values! You have to decide list of what entities you want to get in the end: ARecords or Strings. If ARecords - then take values of a Map, if Strings - take keySet.

Comment: I want keySet. Once I get that, I pass into another method which takes in List<ARecord>. I can't figure out how to pass the keys of hash map as a List<ARecord>

Comment: @Jay: That statement makes no sense.  The keys are `String`s.  "how to pass the keys of hash map as a List<ARecord>" makes no sense, because the _keys are not `ARecord`s._  That's the _values._

Comment: @Jay, if the records in `uniqueRecs` are indeed unique as the name implies, meaning that all `ARecord`s in the map have unique ids, then you can simply use `new ArrayList<>(uniqueRecs.values())` as ka4eli is suggesting here.

Comment: Thank you - to elaborate/explain further  `keySet()` returns a `Set` and this `extends` the `Collection` class. `values()` returns a `Collection`. This : `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` from `ArrayList` constructor makes it valid.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me that i wanted to modify an existing list was:

```
list.addAll(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to do this 'nowadays' is:

```
List<Integer> result = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will **not** throw any warnings and will get the `List<Integer>` generic correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following works under Java 1.7 and 1.8:

```
List<ARecord> finalRecs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
for (final String key : uniqueRecs.keySet()) {
  finalRec.add(new ARecord() {
    public String gettld() {
       return key;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an error"The method addAll(Collection<? extends ARecord>) in the type List<ARecord> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<String>)"

Comment: @Jay revised the answer to populate the list with the Map's values not the keys.

Comment: I actually want the keys. Is there any way to get keys and convert to List<ARecord>?

Comment: it's an interface: public interface ARecord {public String gettId()}